# How does the area under the curve mean the total exposure to the drug?

Tags: pharmacology

I was wondering how the area under the curve in the case of a conc against time plot would be equal to the total exposure in the body? I know that this area is integrated using

> AUC = ∫C dt

However wouldn't that mean - according to my understanding - that the product of this is the sum between the total conc of the drug and the time as the latter is a part of the calculation? And if it's the case, wouldn't that mean the AUC isn't just the total exposure?

Comment: can you post a reference for this, whatever the materials you're looking at? a diagram might also be helpful if you can post one. It also isn't clear to me what your logic is. To me, it makes sense that if I've had 10µM drug at time 0, 8µM at time 1, 2µM at time 2, that overall my body has experienced 20µM of the drug if those are the 3 (hypothetical, infinitesimally short) times that we care about. Can you be more specific why this doesn't make sense to you?

Comment: I would think of this as a *definition*: the *definition* of "total exposure" is the product of concentration and time, in other words, the area under the curve if the curve is time versus concentration.

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. Please finish reading the [Tour] and edit your title so it has some meaning. Referring to “the curve” just will not do. You need to say what the curve plots, and if that seems too long-winded, give a title that expresses the concept involved. In any case the curve should be described in full (preferably as an illustration) in the question itself.

Comment: Wikipedia has an article on [AUC] (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_under_the_curve_(pharmacokinetics). You should read it. It represents the total drug concentration the body was exposed to. Per the Wiki article, it can be used to compare tissue exposure to different formulations (capsules/tablets) of drugs.

Comment: If by you, you mean me, there is no obligation on me to read an article that some anonymous person has written on Wikipedia to clarify a phrase in plain English that is so vague as to be useless in a title. In your actual question, where you use the abbreviation AUC (the codon for isoleucine, I presume) you do not define it. You still have not done us the courtesy to finish reading the [Tour] of this site which explains how it works, but presume to tell us what we should do. Read it, then you will learn what you should do.